# Given three polynomials $a(x), b(x)$, and $c(x)$ satisfying $\gcd(a(x), b(x), c(x))=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, principal-ideal-domains

Given three nonzero polynomials $a(x), b(x)$ and $c(x)$ satisfying $\gcd(a(x), b(x), c(x))=1$.

Please help me prove that there exists six polynomials $f(x), g(x), h(x), u(x), v(x), w(x)$ such that

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a(x) & b(x) & c(x) \\ 
f(x) & g(x) & h(x) \\ 
u(x) & v(x) & w(x) 
\end{vmatrix}=1$$

Comment: What does $(a(x),b(x),c(x)) = 1$ stand for? Should you equations hold for all $x$ (in $\mathbb{R}$), or just for one? Where are your own ideas?

Comment: @Bemte It means the greatest common divisor of three polynomials.I have edited in the problem just now. I am so sorry.

Comment: @Bemte The equation holds for all x.

Comment: @MooS But they are polynomials this time, not integers.

Comment: They are elements of a principal ideal domain. That is precisely the context of the other question. Clear duplicate imho.

Comment: @MooS  Oh yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G(x) := \gcd(a(x),b(x))$.

Then there are polynomials $A(x), B(x)$ such that $a(x)A(x) + b(x)B(X) = G(x)$.

Now we know that $\gcd(G(x),c(x)) = 1$.

Thus, there are polynomials $C(x),D(x)$ such that $G(x)D(x) + c(x)C(x) = 1$.

Expand this to read $$a(x)A(x)D(x) + b(x)B(X)D(x) + c(x)C(x) = 1$$

Look at the formula for the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix and try to take it from there.

Comment: Thank you but I have come to this. I suspect that the difficulty is in making 6 polynomials satisfying the equation.

Comment: @MooS has got the answer.